Same sequence resolving two seemingly unrelated problems
While solving this nice problem by Prof. Zagier

Somebody incorrectly remembered Fermat's little theorem as saying that the congruence holds $ a^{n+1} = a\bmod{n}$ holds for all $a$ if $n$ is prime. Describe the set of integers $n$ for which this property is in fact true.

I noticed that the solution $ (n = 1, 2, 6, 42, 1806 $ here the oeis sequence)  is the same sequence that resolves this seemingly unrelated problem

Find all the numbers $m$ such that $k^m + (k+1)^m + ... + (k+m-1)^m$ is prime for some $k$.

Is there any reason for that? Are these problems related?

I will show that if $m$ is a solution to the second problem, then it is a solution to the first. (Since all solutions to the first problem are solutions to the second, the sequences are the same.)
Let $p$ be a prime factor of $m$. Working modulo $p$, the sum becomes
$$\bigg(k^m+(k+1)^m+\dots+(k+p-1)^m\bigg) + \bigg(k^m+(k+1)^m+\dots+(k+p-1)^m\bigg) + \dots + \bigg(k^m+(k+1)^m+\dots+(k+p-1)^m\bigg)$$
where there are $\frac{m}{p}$ copies of $\bigg(k^m+(k+1)^m+\dots+(k+p-1)^m\bigg)$.
Therefore, the whole sum is a multiple of $p$ if either $p^2\mid m$ or the sum of all $m$th powers mod $p$ is $0$ mod $p$.
Standard lemma: The sum of all $m$th powers mod $p$ is $0$ mod $p$ iff $p-1\mid m$. (Proof: If $p-1\mid m$ then by Fermat's little theorem all $m$th powers except for $0^m$ are 1 mod $p$, so the sum is $p-1\pmod{p}$. For the converse, for any nonzero residue class $r\pmod{p}$, the sum of all $m$th powers is invariant under multiplication by $r^m$. Therefore if $r^m\ne1$ then the sum of all $m$th powers must be $0\pmod{p}$. So the only way the sum can be nonzero mod $p$ is if $r^m\cong1\pmod{p}$ for all nonzero residue classes $r$. Taking $r$ to be a primitive root mod $p$ gives the claim.)
Therefore, necessary conditions for $m$ to be a solution to the second problem include:

$m$ is squarefree
For any prime factor $p$ of $m$, it holds that $p-1\mid m$.

(In more detail: I've shown that if either condition fails then $p$ divides the sum, so the only way the sum can be prime is if the sum is $\pm p$. But for $m\ge3$, the sum (if nonzero) is too large to be $\pm p$ because $p\le m<2^m<\lvert \textrm{the sum}\rvert$ (even if $k$ is allowed to be negative, because all terms that don't get cancelled out have the same sign).)
These are exactly the conditions for $m$ to satisfy being a solution to the first problem (as detailed in the first two paragraphs of the solution linked in the question).
(This isn't terribly satisfying because the squarefree requirement for the two problems arise in completely different ways, and the second requirement is similar only in that both can be argued in terms of primitive roots, so for now the best I can say is that the sequences of solutions are the same because both of them can be described as the set of numbers satisfying the above two conditions.)

Nice +1 from me
